# Group a list of objects by property and remove the first value from each group

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a list of Students and I want group this list by the property `NAME`, to sort each group `ASC` by the property `GRADE`, to remove the first entry from each Group  and after thatto return the proccesed list.

Here is what I've done.

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.security.KeyStore.Entry;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Student studentA2 = new Student("A", 1);
        Student studentA1 = new Student("A", 2);
        Student studentA3 = new Student("A", 3);
        Student studentA4 = new Student("A", 5);
        Student studentA5 = new Student("A", 9);
        Student studentB4 = new Student("B", 0);
        Student studentB1 = new Student("B", 10);
        Student studentB2 = new Student("B", 4);
        Student studentB3 = new Student("B", 2);

        List<Student> allStudents = new LinkedList<>();

        allStudents.addAll(Arrays.asList(studentA1, studentA2, studentA3, studentB1, studentB2, studentB3, studentA4,
                studentA5, studentB4));

        List<Student> procesedList = doGroupValuesAndRemoveTheSmallestGrade(allStudents);

        // The entry: Student("A", 1) and new Student("B", 0) are removed;
        procesedList.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.name + " " + x.grade));
    }

    private static List<Student> doGroupValuesAndRemoveTheSmallestGrade(List<Student> allStudents) {
        Collections.sort(allStudents, Comparator.comparing(Student::getName).thenComparing(Student::getGrade));

        Map<String, LinkedList<Student>> groupedStudents = new HashMap<>();

        for (Student student : allStudents) {

            boolean isNewGroup = groupedStudents.get(student.getName()) == null;

            if (isNewGroup) {
                groupedStudents.put(student.getName(), new LinkedList<>());
            }

            groupedStudents.get(student.getName()).add(student);
        }

        groupedStudents.forEach((k, v) -> v.removeFirst());

        List<Student> procesedList = new ArrayList<>();

        groupedStudents.forEach((k, childList) -> childList.forEach(student -> procesedList.add(student)));
        return procesedList;
    }

}

class Student {
    public String name;
    public int grade;

    public Student(String name, int grade) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(int grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No point in having named individual variables for your `Student` instances - add them to the list inline. Also, don't construct the list directly; just accept the result of `asList`.

Make `Student` a record.

`Student` is not a great name for what actually appears to be a `StudentGrade`.

`doGroupValuesAndRemoveTheSmallestGrade` is a painful name. You're better off abbreviating this to something like `groupAndTrim`, and adding meaningful javadocs for the details.

`doGroupValuesAndRemoveTheSmallestGrade` can be re-expressed in streams, and would then return a stream instead of a list.

You should replace `println` with `printf`. Better yet, do it in memory by formatting strings and then sending them to a single `print`.

`main` should go away and be replaced with an actual unit test.

### Suggested

There are probably better places to put `groupAndTrim`, but those depend on the broader context of "what you're actually doing" which you have not shown. In the absence of a fully-defined data processing pipeline I have shown this as a static on `StudentGrade` itself.

Demonstrating some of the above,

```
package com.stackexchange.studentgroup;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public record StudentGrade(
    String name,
    int grade
) {
    
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%s %d", name, grade);
    }

    /**
     * Sort by student name and then by grade. Drop each student's lowest grade.
     */
    public static Stream<StudentGrade> groupAndTrim(Collection<StudentGrade> grades) {
        return grades.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                StudentGrade::name
            ))
            .values().stream()
            .flatMap(
                students ->
                    students.stream()
                        .sorted(
                            Comparator.comparing(StudentGrade::grade)
                        )
                        .skip(1)
            );
    }
}
```

```
package com.stackexchange.studentgroup;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;


public class GroupTest {
    @Test
    public void testGroupTrim() {

        List<StudentGrade> grades = Arrays.asList(
            new StudentGrade("A", 2),
            new StudentGrade("A", 1),
            new StudentGrade("A", 3),
            new StudentGrade("B", 10),
            new StudentGrade("B", 4),
            new StudentGrade("B", 2),
            new StudentGrade("A", 5),
            new StudentGrade("A", 9),
            new StudentGrade("B", 0)
        );

        List<StudentGrade> processed = StudentGrade.groupAndTrim(grades).toList();

        // The entry: Student("A", 1) and new Student("B", 0) are removed

        assertEquals(7, processed.size());

        for (StudentGrade grade: grades) {
            boolean copied = processed.contains(grade);

            int shouldDrop = switch(grade.name()) {
                case "A" -> 1;
                case "B" -> 0;
                default -> throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            };

            assertTrue((grade.grade() == shouldDrop) ^ copied);
        }
    }
}
```